# Accepted answer subject to random sorting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, sorting, self-answer

I answered one of my questions (see [How can I use Microsoft Word's spelling/grammar checker programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646801/how-can-i-use-microsoft-words-spelling-grammar-checker-programmatically)) and accepted it but it randomly appears first or second (out of two answers).

[image: OMGWTFBBQ]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by design.

accepting your own answer confers no sorting benefits. See this and other rules:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: ah, maybe this explains the recent spate of wonky sorting i've been witnessing on SU (and meta too, it seems).  as a random reader (neither the question poster nor an answer poster), i've been very confused about why an accepted answer isn't at the top of a by-vote-sorted list of answers.  i haven't checked that all the observed cases are indeed answered-by-questioner, so maybe that's it.  but as an exception to the general sorting rule for accepted answers, it just makes me think that something's broken.

Comment: sorry, this is by design