# Why can't I get reputation for accepting my own answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, self-answer

I want to know why I don't get reputation after accepting my own answer.

Comment: The same reason that you can't upvote your own answers.

Comment: /megaultrafacepalm

Comment: @gnat I would argue that that FAQ doesn't answer **Why**

Comment: @RichardTingle this and other rules of the game for accepted self-answers appear to be covered by Jeff himself in [Accepted answer subject to random sorting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/accepted-answer-subject-to-random-sorting) - which probably would be a better dupe in this case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would be too easy to abuse the system, and gain reputation by repeatedly asking questions, answering them, and accepting those answers. Here is a [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) Jeff wrote about the subject.