# Why is this accepted answer not listed at the top?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer, sorting

Answer in question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12827086/825789

I have the answers sorted by votes, but strangely the answer marked as accepted is listed last. The top answer is the one with most votes:

[image]

I've never seen that happen before. Is it because the answer was posted by the asker, or is it a bug?

Comment: Self accepts aren't pinned to the top.

Comment: Also: [Accepted answer subject to random sorting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28063)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Voting to close as duplicate too. Or should I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By design. The accepted answer is by the question asker, so it sorts based purely by votes rather than being forced to the top.

Comment: I suspected that right before posting this question...

Answer (score 1):

When an accepted answer was posted by the person who asked the question it is not shown first; it is shown where the votes on it would put it.

Answer (score 1):

When the OP writes an answer and accepts it, it is not automatically pinned to the top. It behaves like there is no accepted answer at all.